# pycharm rerun button don't start application?

Tags: pycharm

I had download newly pycharm, but when i click rerun button, the pycharm do dothing, just restart the ipython.

> [image]

My Setting:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Rerun button will not restart your application but just the Python Console.

If you want restart application you should use PyCharm Configuration. 
You can easily add a configuration clicking on:

```
Run --> Edit Configuration
```

Then, clicking on the plus icon, you can add a new configuration based on your project type.

Once configuration has been created, you can start your application using the configuration.

Start application clicking on:

```
Run --> Run 'configuration_name'
```

Now, like Python Console, you can start, rerun and abort you application.

Comment: I can set it 'rerun' to start a application with system shell, but not ipython shell.Can you give me more detail setting?

Comment: Sorry, you want more details about what? How to set up configuration?

Comment: yes, rerun work fine for system shell, but in ipython it not working.